# htaccess: redirecting php query string to filename

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This looks simple but I do not know what thing is going wrong. I am using MAMP on MacOS and mod_rewrite is already enabled. Below is the `.htaccess` content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ view.php?symbol=$1 [NC,L]
```

The URL `http://localhost/pe/data/view.php?symbol=APPL` should be accessed if someone visits: `http://localhost/pe/data/APPL.html`

I am getting a 404.

The htaccess file exists in `/data/` folder.

Comment: You specified `RewriteBase /`, so the relative substitution path `view.php` will effectively point to `http://localhost/view.php`

Comment: @CBroe it works after removing but does not when I change it to `RewriteBase /data`.

Comment: Maybe that would be because the path from the root is `/pe/data`, and not just `/data` ...

Answer (score 0):

The 404 results because the rule rewrites the request to `/view.php` (as indicated by the `RewriteBase` directive), not `/pe/data/view.php` as intended.

If the `.htaccess` file is in the `/pe/data` directory and the URLs you are requesting are relative to this directory and `view.php` is located in this directory (as appears to be the case) then you should... **remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely**.

The `RewriteBase` directive specifies an *alternative* URL-path to use for relative path substitutions. `view.php` (without a slash prefix or scheme+hostname) is a relative path. The *default path* is the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file (the *directory-prefix*). So, if you are rewriting to the *default path*, you don't need the `RewriteBase` directive at all.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ view.php?symbol=$1 [NC,L]
> ```

Minor point, but the `NC` flag is entirely superfluous here.